# Is there a way to 'peg' the size of a font to the size of the browser window (with and height and line height, padding etc)?

Tags: css, sass

This is a CSS question (maybe with a js answer) that has driven me nuts for years. This question has been asked many times on SO as 'peg to width' of window but it needs to be to height too, and it also needs to take margins and padding and line height into account.

If I change the font size at various break points, there are too many variations these days in screen dimensions (with plenty more to come).

Is there a good non-Javascript way of doing this in CSS? I'd assume a formula would be needed, maybe it could only be done in sass? It would need to hold the ratios between everything in place though. The closest thing I've seen is here https://impactcentral.co.uk

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it could be done with some combination of `vw`, `vh`, `vmin` or `vmax` [Relative length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units)

Comment: vmin for everything? Except to maintain readability you'd probably need some min settings so not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

One idea from the future is to use `element()` that allow you to transform your text into background and rely on `background-size:contain` but there is [no good support](https://caniuse.com/css-element-function) right now.

A working example that you can test on Firefox. Resize your screen in all the ways and the text will fit the screen dimension with no distortion.

```css
#text {
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100vmax;
  left: -100vmax;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: -moz-element(#text) center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">Some text</div>
```

Another example with a resizable div:

```css
#text {
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100vmax;
  left: -100vmax;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: -moz-element(#text) center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">Some text</div>

<div class="box"></div>
```